# Dockerized pgAdmin4: explain functionality not working / tables not visible in UI

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I've been trying to fix this for two days now. I've followed a [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dockerized-crud-restful-api-with-go-gorm-jwt-postgresql-mysql-and-testing-61d731430bd8) to setup postgres with pgadmin using docker. Since I need postgis I modified the tutorial to get the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  fullstack-postgres: # https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/
    image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
    container_name: full_db_postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}  
      - POSTGRES_PASS=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DBNAME=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data/:/var/lib/postgresql
    networks:
      - fullstack

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-postgres
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - fullstack
    restart: unless-stopped                

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

After running `docker-compose up` I can access pgadmin on localhost:5050. I'm able to connect with my postgres instance. In order to connect I do `object>create>server`. In the connection tab I then give the postgres docker container id to connect:

[image]

I now can create a table e.g.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   loc_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   text VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   loc POINT NOT NULL,
   time TIMESTAMP
);
```

Which is working. I can insert data into my table and query it without problem. The issues are in pgadmin:

- I cannot see my table(s) in the UI browser on the left
- The explain tab is not showing anything

It feels pgadmin4 didn't get configured properly. Any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the same database in both cases?

Comment: when creating the server I fill my username and pwd which are the ones given to the postgres docker image. If I give different credentials then pgadmin complains. Which I imagine means I'm connecting to the postgres inside docker.

Comment: I am not talking about username and password (users are the same for all databases), but the database name to which you connect.

Comment: regardless the one I'm connecting to I should see it on the left panel along with its table(s) no? I m confident I'm connecting to the right one. I was thinking the problem could be more related to network issues, I've found some old mention of missing tables in UI and no explain function due to using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 but couldn't find how to use this insight in my case.

Comment: I think you are encountering a known bug: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4806